# Outlook Attachment Remove event triggers even if attachment is not really added

Tags: .net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

In my VSTO application I'm capturing outlook mail item **AttachmentRemove** event and doing some required handling. I tried to add a huge file and outlook throws below error which is expected.
[image]

What I noticed is that, this case triggers **AttachmentRemove** event (which is not intended for me). Why is it so? Is there any way to differentiate this from usual attachment removal.  I want my **AttachmentRemove** event handler to run only for  removal of attachments which were successfully added earlier in outlook. How do I achieve this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it matter? Check the `Attachment.FileName` property, and if it is not something you recognize, just ignore it.